# Maximum no. of builds in iTunes Store

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, itunes-store

Is there any limit on number of builds for a single version of ios app in iTunes Store?

I am uploading builds and submitted for review to iTunes.

Do iTunes have limitation on no. of builds we send them for review.

( We are in extensive beta testing phase and we have submitted over 7 builds for review )

Any Suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: surely you only send for review when you actually want the app to go live?

Comment: @Fonix, I fix changes made by beta testers and upload to iTunes Stores and make app available to them. When they will approve fully then I will submit to appstore.
So how many no of such builds i can make and submit to iTunes for review. Till now i have submitted 7 builds to iTunes they have approved till now. I want to know their limit (how many they review or they get irritated with no. of builds.)

Comment: Are you talking about builds that you're submitting to the app store, or builds for testing in Testflight?

Comment: I'm talking about builds for testing in Testflight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple wan't prevent to upload **multiple** build for **Test flight beta** testing. but at a time, you can enable **single** build for **beta testing**. once you enable build for beta testing, other builds are autometic goes in **inactive** state.

To sent you desire build for Beta testing, you need to keep **TestFlight Beta Testing** switch `On` like as belowed.
[image]

[UploadingBinariesforanApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

For builds submitted for TestFlight beta testing, there's no limit indicated in the docs. [The instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html) simply say:

> Upload new builds as you develop them.

Builds submitted for app store approval have always been considered one at a time. There's nothing to prevent you from uploading a newer build, but it usually sends your app to the back of the review queue. In the past, the approval process sometimes took a week or more, so developers tried to be as careful as possible about what they submitted. The process seems more automated now, and with an initial review happening before your app is even accepted for beta testing, the "penalty" for submitting an updated build while a previous one is in progress may not be so great.

Comment: I have already uploaded 7 builds in a row for my first version.

Comment: Sure, they won't stop you from uploading as many as you like, but every time you submit your app goes back to the end of the line. Why would Apple waste time reviewing your first build when you've already submitted a second, third, etc?